# Apple Wallet Coupon example create fail

Tags: coupon, wallet, passkit

Since I success create a boarding pass using C# in asp.net, I going to try difference type of pass such coupon and event pass. When I try to create a Coupon pass in .net, it became fail. At first, I believe is my wrong of my coding, I go to try all the creation step in mac with Terminal with [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1) doc.

However the answer is **Fail**, the coupon pass cannot create successful, event I using those example provided by Apple himself ([developer downloads area](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH1-SW1)).

Any one know what happen is it?

Comment: Not just Coupon, but also Event ticket is fail too

Comment: What do you mean by "Fail"?  What are you seeing that makes you concluded that it failed?

Comment: @PassKit The Fail means cannot open successful in iPhone, after click the button on email of pkpass or using web service to auto download, the screen of iPhone will redirect to home page. Noted that  the webServiceURL in pass.json already set to https for production testnig

Comment: Still not enough information to debug. Can you post a link to the .pkpass bundle

Comment: Have provided an answer based on your pass.  BTW, we are a HK based company that may be able to help you with your project. https://passkit.com

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your JSON contains invalid data:

```
"auxiliaryFields":[{"key":        "expires",
                    "label":      "EXPIRES",
                    "value":      "0880",
                    "isRelative": true,
                    "dateStyle":  "PKDateStyleShort"}],
```

The `value` for this dictionary should be an [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted date.

E.g. `2016-11-10T23:59:59+08:00`

Comment: Thank you for your ans, however I believe this problem not just easy to find out. The file "WalletCompanionFiles" is provided by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/iOS/Wallet_Support_Materials/WalletCompanionFiles.zip) and there also have a Coupon example, that example also failed even using Terminal to create, do you have any ideas for this? Any way, thanks for your reply and I didn't know your company is HK based! It shock me!

Comment: Most likely the example is using an old WWDR certificate.  Hook your phone up to Xcode and read the console logs when adding the pass to get the exact reason it is failing